# Unable to test username/password with JDBC query

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc

I am trying to make a login form that connects to an SQL database. Here is my code:

```
private void cmd_loginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    String sql="Selet * from inventor1";
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn= (Connection); 
             DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventor","root","root");
        Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        String user=t1.getText();
        String pass=new String(t2.getText());
        while(rs.next()){
            String username=rs.getString("username");
            String password=rs.getString("password");
            if(user.equals("username") && pass.equals("password")){
                new Mainmenu().setVisible(true); 
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "password and username not match");
    }
}
```

However the username and password never seem to match, even though what I enter matches what is in the database. Why does the username and password never match?

Comment: Just print `e.printStackTrace()` to see any exceptions you're getting. You're skipping it off (it's a bad practice)

Comment: Does your real program say "selet" in the ``sql`` string? That should be "select", I think.

Comment: Why would you select all the rows in the database and read through them all trying to find a match? That is not very efficient.

Instead you should be using a select statement with a where clause to match your userid and password. You can start by reading a tutorial on [JDBC Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) for some basic of SQL.

Comment: And if we're on the subject of best practices for storing log-in information, don't forget about hashing your passwords!

Answer (score 3):

First of all Typos *(Must be)*:

- `Selet * from inventor1` Should be `Select` instead of `Selet`
- `Connection conn= (Connection); <---- Remove ;`

Now as you might be getting `Exception` but you are swallowing it by the use of

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "password and username not match");
```

So I think the reason of this problem is your query which is throwing `SQLException` every time because of `Selet`.

Secondly you are retrieving all data by the use of `*` I guess your table only has two columns username and password than it's fine but it's really good practice in programming to be more specific in your code.

Answer (score 1):

There's an extra semicolon here

```
Connection conn= (Connection); 
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventor","root","root");
```

I think you want

```
Connection conn= (Connection) 
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventor","root","root");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't that the password doesn't match (if that were the problem, the code would simply never make the main menu visible but would not throw an error). Rather, an error is being thrown (likely due to a problem with the connection to the database). More information is needed to diagnose the exact problem, so for starters try replacing this:

```
catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "password and username not match");
}
```

with this:

```
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "An error occurred, see log for details.");
}
```

In general, it is bad practice to simply catch an `Exception` and then ignore it, as your code segment does, precisely because of this problem. Once you have an error message, you can research the problem on your own and then post the message here if you are still unable to resolve the issue.